# Hot reload on React with docker-compose failing on Windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get React to change content of the site when it's file is being saved.

I'm using VS code which doesn't have safe write. I'm using docker-compose on Windows via Docker Desktop.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /front

ARG FRONT_CMD
ARG API_HOSTNAME

ENV REACT_APP_API_HOSTNAME=$API_HOSTNAME

COPY . .
RUN npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled
CMD $FRONT_CMD
```

relevant part of docker-compose.yml:

```
  frontend:
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/front/src
      - /front/node_modules
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - FRONT_CMD=${FRONT_CMD}
        - API_HOSTNAME=${API_HOSTNAME}
    env_file:
        - .env.dev
    networks:
      - internal
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        - FAST_REFRESH=false
        - NODE_ENV=development
```

Everything is running behind traefik. CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING and FAST_REFRESH seem to make no difference, I start with ' docker-compose --env-file ..env.dev up' - within the file FRONT_CMD="npm start" which behaves just fine. Env.dev should be clear indication of dev build (and is, works the same without the addition) to React, but I added NODE_ENV just be safe. I tried adding all of them into build envs just be super sure, but nothing changes. React files lay in 'frontend' folder, which is in the same location as docker-compose.yml.

Every time React says it compiled successfully and warns me that it's a development build.

Only suspicion I have left is that there's some issue with updating files with Windows locally while docker uses Linux, but I have no idea where to go from there even if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest way I found was to start from the other side, that is attach editor to container instead of updating container based on changes in system files. I followed the guide here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container